# How to replace keypress event in dojo?

Tags: events, dojo, keypress

I have a dropdown with values-Name,MobileNumber and a input text-box related to the selected dropdown.

I want to limit the textbox entry values with only alphabet when Name is selected from the dropdown and only Numbers when MobileNumber is selected. This I am achieving by adding the below thing.

*

```
   On(dom.byId("dropdownid"), "keypress", function(e)){
if(dom.byId("dropdownid").value=="Name"){
     On(dom.byId("textboxid"), "keypress", function(e){
        if(RegularExpressionAlphabetOnlyCondition == e.charCode){
        Stopping the event using e.stopEvent();
        }
        });
}
if(dom.byId("dropdownid").value=="MobileNumber"){
     On(dom.byId("textboxid"), "keypress", function(e){
        if(RegularExpressionNumbersOnlyCondition == e.charCode){
        Stopping the event using e.stopEvent();
        }
        });
}
});
```

*

Now on change of the dropdown value I am adding change event for dropdown and adding similar keypressevent with regularexpression condition of only numbers.
But its not working and accepting only alphabet still. It is apparently not replacing the already placed keypressevent.

How to remove the Keypress event in dojo for a textbox on change of a dropdown value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on Function returnes a handle

```
var h =  On(dom.byId("textboxid"), "keypress", function(e){console.log("do Stuff"});
```

You can then use the handle to cancel it listener before doing a new one

```
if(h)h.remove();
```